# See if something is of type class

Tags: c#, class, types

I am trying to check to see if something is a certain type of class in c#. It prints out certain labels on a form depending on what class it is a type of. This is what I have so far and it works for the "if" statement. However, I get an error of "unable to cast object of type". Is it possible to use an if-else statement in this scenario?

```
public void ShowStaffData(string pName)
{
  //Gets Staff Details from the name slected int he list box in the form
  people.CreatePeople();
  var currentPerson = 
    people.person.Where(p => p.Forename + " " + p.Surname == pName);

  // How the info is printed out if person selected in 
  // a member of Accademic Staff
  AccademicStaff accademic = currentPerson as AccademicStaff;

  if (currentPerson!=null)
  {
    foreach (AccademicStaff accStaff in currentPerson)
    {
      label9.Text = accStaff.Forename + " " + accStaff.Surname;
      label10.Text = accStaff.IdentificationNumber.ToString();
      label11.Text = accStaff.DateOfBirth;
      label12.Text = accStaff.Address;
      label13.Text = accStaff.Office;
      label14.Text = accStaff.School;
      label15.Text = accStaff.ModuleLeaderOf;
      label16.Text = accStaff.ProgramLeaderOf;
    }
  }      
  else
  {
    // How the info is printed out if person selected in 
    // a member of Admin Staff

    foreach (AdminStaff admin in currentPerson)
    {
      label9.Text = admin.Forename + " " + admin.Surname;
      label10.Text = admin.IdentificationNumber.ToString();
      label11.Text = admin.DateOfBirth;
      label12.Text = admin.Address;
      label13.Text = admin.Office;
      label6.Text = "Job Role";
      label14.Text = admin.JobRole;
      label7.Dispose();
      label8.Dispose();
      label15.Dispose();
      label16.Dispose();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What line are you getting the error on?

Comment: Maybe the [`is`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) operator helps?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, `currentPersion` is a collection of items. Use the `Single` method to make it a single item:

```
var currentPerson =
  people.person.Where(p => p.Forename + " " + p.Surname == pName).Single();
```

(If it's possible that you don't get a match at all, you would use `SingleOrDefault` and then check if `currentPersion` is null.)

Second, after trying to cast you are checking the `currentPerson` variable instead of the `accademic` variable:

```
AccademicStaff accademic = currentPerson as AccademicStaff;
if (accademic != null)
```

Now you don't need the loops either. Use the `accademic` variable in the first section, and cast the reference to `AdminStaff` in the second:

```
AdminStaff admin = currentPerson as AdminStaff;
```

Comment: And this is why this guys rep is 220K+

Comment: Only use Single() if pName is unique. If there could be multiple people of the same name then don't use Single() and handle each record using foreach (or use FirstOrDefault() and check for null) if you want a single record. If pName is unique but might not match a record use SingleOrDefault() rather than Single()

Comment: you can also check type with : if (currentPerson.GetType() == typeof(AccademicStaff)) { ... } else { ... }

Comment: @AndyNichols: The way that the code is made I assume that there can't be more than one match. If there would be, you would need a completely different way to display the results. Looping a result and putting them in the same labels would be pointless.

Comment: @Guffa, yes, just edited my comment. Might still need SingleOrDefault() rather than Single().

Comment: @Xaruth: You don't need to get the `Type` objects, just use `if (currentPersion is AccademicStaff)`.

Comment: This worked an absolute treat Thank you so much. I have been messing around with it for a few days and unable to make it work. Thanks

Comment: @AndyNichols: I already added a note about `SingleOrDefault` to the answer, even before I saw your first comment. :)

Answer (score 2):

Move the `if ... else ...` bit into the `foreach` loop, since your where selector is returning a collection, not a single person.

```
var currentPerson = people.person.Where(p => p.Forename + " " + p.Surname == pName);

foreach (var person in currentPerson)
{

    AccademicStaff accStaff = person as AccademicStaff;
    if (accStaff != null)
    {
        label9.Text = accStaff.Forename + " " + accStaff.Surname;
        label10.Text = accStaff.IdentificationNumber.ToString();
        label11.Text = accStaff.DateOfBirth;
        label12.Text = accStaff.Address;
        label13.Text = accStaff.Office;
        label14.Text = accStaff.School;
        label15.Text = accStaff.ModuleLeaderOf;
        label16.Text = accStaff.ProgramLeaderOf;
    }
    else
    {
        // How the info is printed out if person selected in a member of Admin Staff
        label9.Text = person.Forename + " " + person.Surname;
        label10.Text = person.IdentificationNumber.ToString();
        label11.Text = person.DateOfBirth;
        label12.Text = person.Address;
        label13.Text = person.Office;
        label6.Text = "Job Role";
        label14.Text = person.JobRole;
    }       
}
```

I removed the calls to `Dispose()` on the labels, they make no sense.

**Edit** You could probably shorten it a bit like this:

```
var currentPerson = people.person.Where(p => p.Forename + " " + p.Surname == pName);

foreach (var person in currentPerson)
{

    label9.Text = person.Forename + " " + person.Surname;
    label10.Text = person.IdentificationNumber.ToString();
    label11.Text = person.DateOfBirth;
    label12.Text = person.Address;
    label13.Text = person.Office;

    AccademicStaff accStaff = person as AccademicStaff;
    if (accStaff != null)
    {
        label14.Text = accStaff.School;
        label15.Text = accStaff.ModuleLeaderOf;
        label16.Text = accStaff.ProgramLeaderOf;
    }
    else
    {
        label6.Text = "Job Role";
        label14.Text = person.JobRole;
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (instance.GetType().IsClass)
{

}
```

Should do the trick.

But you shouldn't really be doing it this way, if you need different classes to print out different things then I'd recommend going down the route of creating an interface and implementing it separately on each type.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `currentPerson` is a single entity not a collection. so `Single` or `FirstOrDefault` would work just as well; ( Depending on if the currentPerson is unique or not ) then to test for the type I prefer using `is` as it handles a null check. So that if none of your labels get populated it means the person returned from the linq statement is of neither type.

```
    people.CreatePeople();
    var currentPerson = people.person.Where(p => p.Forename + " " + p.Surname == pName).Single();

        if(currentPerson is AcademicStaff)
        {
            label9.Text = accStaff.Forename + " " + accStaff.Surname;
            label10.Text = accStaff.IdentificationNumber.ToString();
            label11.Text = accStaff.DateOfBirth;
            label12.Text = accStaff.Address;
            label13.Text = accStaff.Office;
            label14.Text = accStaff.School;
            label15.Text = accStaff.ModuleLeaderOf;
            label16.Text = accStaff.ProgramLeaderOf;
        }
        else if(currentPerson is AdminStaff)
        {
            label9.Text = admin.Forename + " " + admin.Surname;
            label10.Text = admin.IdentificationNumber.ToString();
            label11.Text = admin.DateOfBirth;
            label12.Text = admin.Address;
            label13.Text = admin.Office;
            label6.Text = "Job Role";
            label14.Text = admin.JobRole;
            label7.Dispose();
            label8.Dispose();
            label15.Dispose();
            label16.Dispose();
        }
```